# How to get a TABLE tag's CAPTION tag to shrink to fit its contents without breaking flow

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to shrink the caption box to fit its text content. Here's what I have:

[image]

Here's what I'm after:

[image]

The usual methods of float, display:inline/inline-block/table all cause variants of the following:

[image]

in which the caption is broken out of the flow and becomes treated as a child element of the table's box.

The table code is nothing special:

```
<table>
<caption>Legendary fictional heroes</caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Power</th><th>Nemesis</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Dazzler</td><td>Sound-to-Light Transformation</td><td>Apocalypse</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>  </table>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish what I want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table elements like `<caption>` and `<legend>` are notoriously difficult to style. One of the common workarounds is to add an inner `<span>` and style that instead. I've put together a quick mock-up for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/sjvLa/

If you don't mind the additional markup, this could be something that works for you.

Comment: Yeah, this is the only means I've found of simulating what I want in a semantically equivalent way. I'm holding out a little longer for a 'pure' solution, but +1 for the effort.

Answer (score -2):

You can't make one row in the table smaller then the others. Why don't you place the caption outside the table using div with correct background-color?

Comment: I'm talking about the CAPTION HTML tag, a daughter tag of TABLE. It would be easy enough to do this with a paragraph otherwise, but CAPTION is a required element for accessible tables.